# Summing a Column of a Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to sum the column "salary." Below is my table.

```
public static void dataTable()
{
DataTable table = GetTable();
}
static DataTable table;
public static DataTable GetTable()
{
table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("player", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("age", typeof(double));
table.Columns.Add("position", typeof(stats.pos));
table.Columns.Add("ovalue", typeof(double));
table.Columns.Add("dvalue", typeof(double));
table.Columns.Add("team", typeof(stats.team));
table.Columns.Add("salary", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("contractYears", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("active", typeof(bool));

table.Rows.Add("AG", 24, stats.pos.SP, 0, 4.2, stats.team.S, 1, 5, true);
table.Rows.Add("AR", 30, stats.pos.SP, 0, 2.6, stats.team.S, 7, 2, true);
table.Rows.Add("JK", 22, stats.pos.SP, 0, 3.2, stats.team.S, 1, 6, true);
}
public class stats
{
public enum pos { fiB, seB, SS, thB, OF, C, DH, SP, RP };
public enum team { S };
}
```

Here is my attempt at adding the salary column:

```
try
{
    object sumobject = (object)table.Compute("Sum(salary)", "active=true");
    double sumdouble = Convert.ToDouble(sumobject);
    payrollLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(sumdouble);
}
catch
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Error in payroll");
}
```

However, the code always skips to the catch. It says that there is a null value in my column, but I didn't enter any. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Monetary field as `int` ?

Comment: Can you give the specific error (copy/paste it)?

Comment: the salary column is doubles

Comment: If I get rid of the catch statement, I get NullReferenceException was unhandled.Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Your code says its an `int`.  `table.Columns.Add("salary", typeof(int));`

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint and see if your table is null at that moment somehow?

Comment: Good catch, I'll change that and see if that helps.

Comment: Running this with the 'stats' code commented out works so it's probably coming from there somewhere. Could you most this part of the code to help us repro your error?

Comment: @BlargleMonster, I'm pretty sure that's the problem--I'm getting a null value from somewhere in the column.

Comment: @Fred Deschenes, would it help if I posted the complete Datatable?

Comment: @user2548227 I meant more that it might have nulled out the whole object.  That you might be calling `Compute` on a null object and getting the error there.  Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: @BlargeMonster, any ideas on how to make to object not null? Many thanks, I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is something to do with the stats.pos or stats.team values.  I removed the references and it works just fine.  What do you have in *stats* object?

Wait... Are you initializing *table* before accessing it?

Comment: Stats is a class to hold those enums.

Comment: public enum pos { fiB, seB, SS, thB, OF, C, DH, SP, RP };
    public enum team { S };

Comment: @user2548227 Where are you calling you static method dataTable() from?  Is it before the try block?

Comment: How would I initialize table?

Comment: What is the code before your try{} block?  I mean are you calling dataTable() at all before accessing the table?

Comment: No, I'm not. I just put it under my form class.

Comment: Can you do the following and try if it works for you: call the dataTable() as the first line of code under try{} and leave the rest of the code as is.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify it using LINQ:

Field as int:

```
var salarySum = table.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<int>("salary"));
```

As double:

```
var salarySum = table.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<double>("salary"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
yourtable.AsEnumerable().Sum(datarow => datarow.Field<int>("salary"));
```